# unable to split Firebase functions in multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with firebase functions and arrived to hundreds of functions, and now it is very hard to manage it in single `index.js` file as shown in their lots of examples

I tried to split that functions in multiple files like:

```
--firebase.json
--functions
  --node_modules
  --index.js
  --package.json
  --app
    --groupFunctions.js
    --authFunctions.js
    --storageFunctions.js
```

In this structure i divide my functions in three categories and put in that three files `groupFunctions.js`, `authFunctions.js`, and `storageFunctions.js`. I then tried to import thise files in `index.js`, but I don't know why it is not working for me.

Here is `groupFunctions.js`

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
module.exports = function(){
    exports.onGroupCreate = functions.database.ref('/groups/{groupId}')
        .onWrite(event => {
            console.log(`A group is created in database named:${event.params.groupId}.`);
            // some logic...
            //...
        })
}
```

Here is `index.js` file:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
module.exports = require("./app/groupFunctions")();
```

My editor not giving any warning in this code. But when I deploy this code with `firebase deploy --only functions`, it does not deploy function. If some functions already exist on firebase console, it remove all functions on deploy.

here is deployment logs:
[image]

question is also asked on [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Working code example:

file structure:

```
--firebase.json
--functions
  --node_modules
  --index.js
  --package.json
  --src
    --groupFunctions.js
    --authFunctions.js
    --storageFunctions.js
```

`index.js` file:

```
require('./src/groupFunctions.js')(exports);
require('./src/authFunctions.js')(exports);
require('./src/storageFunctions.js')(exports);
```

`groupFunctions.js` file:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

module.exports = function (e) {
    e.onGroupCreate = functions.database.ref('/groups/{groupId}')
        .onWrite(event => {
            console.log(`A group is created in database named:${event.params.groupId}.`);
            // some logic...
            //...
        })
}
```

## UPDATE: now I have better solution

The full working code is located at https://github.com/malikasinger1/firebase-functions-with-typescript and it's written with cutting edge tech like typescript and webpack. You may use this as a boilerplate/starter.

Comment: Best approach I've seen so far. Made it easy to organise my functions. Having an elephant index.js started to drive me crazy.

Comment: Where should `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` be? As firebase will return error when called `initializeApp()` more than once...

Comment: @andrewsee i have updated answer, may more helpful for you

Comment: @andrei-lupsa see my new approach, may help you more to organize your code

Comment: do you have the same without typescript?

Comment: The code included in my answer is plain JavaScript (no typescript) the typescript one is in my git repository and i just mentioned the link of that repo in the answer because some of you may found it useful

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `exports` object to the function in `groupFunctions.js`, like this:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

module.exports = function (e) {
    e.onGroupCreate = functions.database.ref('/groups/{groupId}')
        .onWrite(event => {
            console.log(`A group is created in database named:${event.params.groupId}.`);
            // some logic...
            //...
        })
}
```

Now, in `index.js`:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

require("./app/groupFunctions")(module.exports);
```

The way it works is that `modules.exports` is a regular JavaScript object, so you can add new properties to that from wherever you want.

Comment: first of all i want it to never change index.js file

Comment: i just want to make an import in inde.js and then do all the work in other files

Comment: removing `()` is also not solving my problem

Comment: the way GCF works is that it reads the index.js, looks at its exports, and deploys every single export as a function.

can you confirm that that `module.exports` of index.js contains the named functions?

Comment: I updated the response with another idea. Let me know whether it worked, so I could update the response.

Comment: Hey your new idea is working... i'm going to edit your answer with working code example

Comment: @InzamamMalik let me update my answer to reflect the working solution. if it works indeed, please mark it as correct:)

Comment: yes please correct it, have a look of my answer which is working example

Answer (score 1):

```
//index.js
const glob = require('glob')
const files = glob.sync('./**/*.functions.js', { cwd: __dirname, 
ignore: './node_modules/**' })

files.forEach(file => {
const functionModule = require(file)
const functionNames = Object.keys(functionModule)

functionNames.forEach(functionName => {
    if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === 
    functionName) {
         exports[functionName] = functionModule[functionName]
     }
  })
 })
```

[Folders like so.. will work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oleXj.png)

```
 //Example Home.functions.js :
 exports.Home = functions.https..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want support for multiple functions inside a file, this Gist show a real example of how to do it

https://gist.github.com/saintplay/3f965e0aea933a1129cc2c9a823e74d7#file-index-js

You can dynamically import functions for every `*.function.js`