# Firebase cloud functions not working after migration to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Recently, I tried migrating my firebase cloud functions from javascript to typescript and split the functions into multiple files. However, I keep getting errors while trying to serve as well as deploy:

**Errors while serving:**

functions[functionName]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
functions[functionName]: function ignored because the firebase emulator does not exist or is not running.

**Error while deploying**:

```
functions[dataDownload(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /srv/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:86
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js:3:44)
```

**Tried:** 
[Firestore/Firebase Emulator Not Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158010/firestore-firebase-emulator-not-running)
(installed the emulators, did firebase init emulators)
[unable to split Firebase functions in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432378/unable-to-split-firebase-functions-in-multiple-files)
[Firestore local http with real db: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running so database operations will fail with a 'default credentials' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125151/firestore-local-http-with-real-db-the-cloud-firestore-emulator-is-not-running-s) 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170#issuecomment-586019131
[How do I structure Cloud Functions for Firebase to deploy multiple functions from multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486278/how-do-i-structure-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-deploy-multiple-functions-fro)
https://javebratt.com/functions-multiple-files/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#migrating_an_existing_javascript_project_to_typescript

**My directory structure:**

```
--functions
    -- lib
    -- node_modules
    -- src
        -- config
        -- admin.ts
        -- index.ts
        -- dataDownload.ts
    -- tsconfig.json
    -- tslint.json
    -- package.json
    -- package-lock.json

--.firebaserc
-firebase.json
--package.json
--package-lock.json
```

**The files:**
index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

import { dataDownloadHandler } from './dataDownload';
export const dataDownload = functions.firestore.document('user/{uid}/download/{downloadId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    dataDownloadHandler(snapshot, context);
});
```

dataDownload.ts:

```
/* 
imports
*/
export const dataDownloadHandler = (snapshot:any, context:any) => {
    // code
}
```

Nor did it work when I moved `dataDownload` function into the dataDownload.ts file and did `export * from './dataDownload;` in `index.ts`.

admin.ts:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const auth = admin.auth();
const rtDb = admin.database();
const fsDb = admin.firestore();
const firebaseTimestamp = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
const firestoreTimestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

export { admin, auth, rtDb, fsDb, firebaseTimestamp, firestoreTimestamp };
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions -P staging",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log -P staging"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.5.0",
    ...other dependencies
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
   },
  "hosting": [
   ...],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT**: `https` cloud functions work; `firestore` and `database` cloud functions don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `"fs-extra": "^9.0.0"` try to downgrade to version `8.1.0`.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. v9.0.0 requires node version >= 10 it seems, whereas cloud functions are still stable only for node v8

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it from your code samples, but everything got deployed properly.

According to this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825313/firebase-cloud-functions-not-working-after-migration-to-typescript) ( you have mentioned it as well) lib/index.js is:

> During firebase deploy, your project's index.ts is transpiled to index.js, meaning that the Cloud Functions log will output line numbers from the index.js file and not the code you wrote. To make it easier for you to find the corresponding paths and line numbers in index.ts

So I suppose you should check what is going on there, how those files look on your side. Maybe you will be able to figure it out.

Also I've found to SO questions that might be helpfull:

[class imported but still firebase deploy fails with Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312958/class-imported-but-still-firebase-deploy-fails-with-cannot-find-module)

[Firebase deploy can't find serviceAccountKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432047/firebase-deploy-cant-find-serviceaccountkey)

Check if your references are not to local files and maybe you can try recreate your project locally and than deploy. I hope this will be helpful!

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the issue in deployment was that one of the dependencies has syntax error. Removing it worked fine. However, testing it using serve still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you running the emulator properly? I wasnt able to reproduce this error ... is there any additional error in the info?

Comment: I removed node_modules, reauthenticated firebase, did npm install, and it's working now. Thank you for your time